# Error failed to resolve 'com.yqritic:recylerview-flexibledivider:1.2.4;

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

zubliquzaini commented just now
Hello, I am getting this issue when I sync the project:

```
Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.yqritic:recylerview-flexibledivider:1.2.4
```

Here's my app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ztl.ztlubricant.testing"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.yqritic:recylerview-flexibledivider:1.2.4'
}
```

I am not sure probably there is a file that I need to download for the yqritic dependencies to work.. 
Help! Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

And try to use version 1.2.6

```
...
compile 'com.yqritc:recyclerview-flexibledivider:1.2.6'
...
```